# Passing the rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hey im building minesweeper game as my project and I have problem passing this test.

```
  it "should initialise each position in each column in matrix as _" do
            matrix = []
            matrix[0] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[1] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[2] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[3] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[4] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[5] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[6] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            @game.clearcolumns
            @game.matrix.should eql matrix
        end
```

This is my simple method:

```
def clearcolumns
        def matrix
            matrix = []
            matrix[0] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[1] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[2] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[3] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[4] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[5] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
            matrix[6] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
        end
    end
```

For some reason I´m getting this fail:

```
Failure/Error: @game.matrix.should eql matrix

       expected: [["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", ... "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]]
            got: ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
```

Comment: also note that having a def inside of a def is probably not what you want

Comment: Something like `Array.new(7, Array.new(7, '-'))` or `[['-'] * 7] * 7` would be shorter.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I would suggest `Array.new(6) { Array.new(6) { '_' } }` otherwise you would add references to the same string multiple time what will lead to unexpected results when the array is updated.

Comment: That's better @spickermann, thanks for that correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods in ruby (without an explicit `return` statement) will return the result of the last line of code that was executed. In your case, your last line of `matrix` is `matrix[6] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]` so that method will always be returning `["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]`. If you want to return the full matrix, you could do this instead:

```
def matrix
  # Initialize the matrix variable
  matrix = []

  # Explicitly set each row of the matrix
  matrix[0] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
  matrix[1] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
  matrix[2] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
  matrix[3] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
  matrix[4] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
  matrix[5] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]
  matrix[6] = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_","_"]

  # Return the matrix
  matrix
end
```